# Cross-talk correction in 2D spectrum using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm working on 2D spectroscopic images, which have four quadrants. Now data from one of the quadrants is cross-talked on to some other quadrants. I am not able to think of a way to remove those cross-talks.

One very basic way I can think of is to remove those using the masking feature of Numpy, but that will also remove the whole data from those pixels, so that is also not useful.

*Edit:
Here is a fits file, which is same as the one shown below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/119MIaBDniMj9dMFRwx_nVLfl6F9X48Rb/view?usp=sharing*

Here is an image in which you can see the cross-talk:
[image]

Comment: this is *like* "echo cancellation" in that you have a signal and fainter copies of it, in the same data. the challenge is estimating what's signal and what's a faint copy of the signal, and what kind of relationship there is between the strength of a signal and the strength of its faint copies. -- got any data to experiment with? [mre]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I uploaded a sample file, you can check that out. It's the same file shown in the image. The actual signal is the one that is in the bottom left corner, which is then copied to other parts of the image. The green arrows in the image describe the same.

Comment: I looked into the file. I can get this visualization (y growing down): https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZRFv.png and I think you've got saturation in your sensor, which causes the echos. this might be solvable with a little masking and subtraction.

Comment: the slanted bands all across the image may also come from sensor saturation. -- I'm getting *some limited* success by subtracting an attenuated (and flipped) copy  of one quadrant from the others. it's not perfect due to the saturation. the peaks of the apparent waveform are more intense in the "original" than they are in the faint copies.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your efforts. Could you please upload what you've done so far? You can update it here as you progress, and simultaneously, I'll also try to make some edits to your code.